"TypeError: request is not iterable" when using Google Gemini API generateContent method in React
I'm working on a React project where I use the Google Gemini API to retrieve information based on inputs collected from a form. However, when I call the generateContent method, I get the following error:
Error generating content: TypeError: request is not iterable
    at formatNewContent (index.mjs:881:36)
    at formatGenerateContentInput (index.mjs:962:25)
    at GenerativeModel.generateContent (index.mjs:1309:33)
    at run (gemini.jsx:32:36)
    at onSent (Context.jsx:59:64)
    at handleSubmit (Main.jsx:20:5)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)

Error Context
This error seems to suggest that the request object isn't formatted correctly or that the Gemini API method expects a different input format. Here's the relevant part of my code where I'm attempting to generate content based on form inputs.
import {
    GoogleGenerativeAI,
    HarmCategory,
    HarmBlockThreshold,
} from "@google/generative-ai";

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GEN_AI_API_KEY; // Ensure this is set in your environment
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
    model: "gemini-1.5-flash",
});

const generationConfig = {
    temperature: 1,
    topP: 0.95,
    topK: 64,
    maxOutputTokens: 8192,
    responseMimeType: "text/plain",
};

export async function run({ education, technologies, level, projects, firstCourse }) {
    try {
        // Log inputs for debugging
        console.log("Inputs for career suggestion:", { education, technologies, level, projects, firstCourse });

        // Career suggestion
        const prompt = `Education: ${education}, skills: ${technologies}, Level: ${level}, Projects_done: ${projects}. Based on my education, skills, and level, which career should I opt for ${firstCourse}? Just tell me one branch in one word.`;
        console.log("Prompt for career suggestion:", prompt);
        
        // Ensure the call to generateContent has the correct structure
        const result = await model.generateContent({ 
            prompt, 
            generationConfig 
        });

        if (!result || typeof result.text !== 'string') {
            throw new Error("Invalid response from model for career suggestion");
        }

        const decision = result.text.trim() || "Unable to determine";

        // Best courses
        const prompt_2 = `${decision} was suggested by a friend. Give me the 5 best free courses with links to master this field, ordered from beginner to advanced. Only list 5 links, no description.`;
        console.log("Prompt for courses:", prompt_2);
        
        const result_2 = await model.generateContent({ 
            prompt: prompt_2, 
            generationConfig 
        });

        if (!result_2 || typeof result_2.text !== 'string') {
            throw new Error("Invalid response from model for courses");
        }

        const courseDisplay = result_2.text.trim() || "No courses found";

        //Trending projects
        const prompt_3 = `For a ${decision} career, suggest 5 trending projects to build my skills at ${level} level.`;
        console.log("Prompt for projects:", prompt_3);
        
        const result_3 = await model.generateContent({ 
            prompt: prompt_3, 
            generationConfig 
        });

        if (!result_3 || typeof result_3.text !== 'string') {
            throw new Error("Invalid response from model for projects");
        }

        const project = result_3.text.trim() || "No projects available";

        return { decision, courseDisplay, project };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error generating content:", error);
        return { decision: "Error", courseDisplay: "Error fetching courses", project: "Error fetching projects" };
    }
}

 export default run;

I want to get response in three things career suggestions, courses and projects kindly help me out in this error.
What I’ve Tried
I verified that my REACT_APP_GEN_AI_API_KEY is set correctly in my environment variables.
Checked that generateContent receives prompt and generationConfig.
Printed prompt and generationConfig to the console, and they appear formatted as expected.

Modification points:

In your script, at const result = await model.generateContent({prompt, generationConfig});, the properties prompt do not exist. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue.
generationConfig can be included in the arguments of genAI.getGenerativeModel.
Also, result.text returns undefined.

When these points are simply reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
import {
  GoogleGenerativeAI,
  HarmCategory,
  HarmBlockThreshold,
} from "@google/generative-ai";

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GEN_AI_API_KEY; // Ensure this is set in your environment
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);

const generationConfig = {
  temperature: 1,
  topP: 0.95,
  topK: 64,
  maxOutputTokens: 8192,
  responseMimeType: "text/plain",
};

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
  model: "gemini-1.5-flash",
  generationConfig,
});

export async function run({ education, technologies, level, projects, firstCourse }) {
  try {
    // Log inputs for debugging
    console.log("Inputs for career suggestion:", { education, technologies, level, projects, firstCourse });

    // Career suggestion
    const prompt = `Education: ${education}, skills: ${technologies}, Level: ${level}, Projects_done: ${projects}. Based on my education, skills, and level, which career should I opt for ${firstCourse}? Just tell me one branch in one word.`;
    console.log("Prompt for career suggestion:", prompt);

    // Ensure the call to generateContent has the correct structure
    const result = await model.generateContent(prompt);

    if (!result || typeof result.response.text() !== "string") {
      throw new Error("Invalid response from model for career suggestion");
    }

    const decision = result.response.text().trim() || "Unable to determine";

    // Best courses
    const prompt_2 = `${decision} was suggested by a friend. Give me the 5 best free courses with links to master this field, ordered from beginner to advanced. Only list 5 links, no description.`;
    console.log("Prompt for courses:", prompt_2);

    const result_2 = await model.generateContent(prompt_2);

    if (!result_2 || typeof result_2.response.text() !== "string") {
      throw new Error("Invalid response from model for courses");
    }

    const courseDisplay = result_2.response.text().trim() || "No courses found";

    //Trending projects
    const prompt_3 = `For a ${decision} career, suggest 5 trending projects to build my skills at ${level} level.`;
    console.log("Prompt for projects:", prompt_3);

    const result_3 = await model.generateContent(prompt_3);

    if (!result_3 || typeof result_3.response.text() !== "string") {
      throw new Error("Invalid response from model for projects");
    }

    const project = result_3.response.text().trim() || "No projects available";

    return { decision, courseDisplay, project };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating content:", error);
    return {
      decision: "Error",
      courseDisplay: "Error fetching courses",
      project: "Error fetching projects",
    };
  }
}

export default run;


When I tested this modified script, I confirmed it worked without errors.

Reference:

Generating content

